# Turkish Characters in the VBA editor

Tags: vba

I have a problem with Turkish characters in my simple VBA code. Whenever I write some text in my module in Turkish characters (e.g. 'ş, ə, ç, ğ, ö, ü, ı"), they change to unknown letters.

I want to change "Eight" to "Səkkiz","Five", "Beş","Three" "Üç" etc.

Comment: 'when i wrote sometext in turkish 'ş, ə, ç, ğ, ö, ü, ı" characters in my module, theese characters changes to unknown letters. I want to change "Eight" to "Səkkiz","Five" "Beş","Three" "Üç" etc' Show your code. – S Nash just now

Comment: @SNash In this case, the code is irrelevant; the problem is the way that the VBA editor handles characters outside its scope. ANY code would have the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The VB editor doesn't support Unicode.  Assuming that wherever you're displaying these characters does, you can do something like this:

```
Const UpsideDownE As Long = &H1DD

Sub Example()
' This would set the currently selected text in PowerPoint to ə
ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.TextFrame.TextRange = ChrW(UpsideDownE)

End Sub
```

Of course, choose names for the constants that make sense to you ... whatever you'd normally call the ə character.

Answer (score 4):

May be you should change Font in the text editor
Try: Tools > Options at the 2nd tab choose Font  Courier New (Turkish)