# What kind of UTF-8 is the one which Excel VBA uses for internal text representation?

Tags: excel, vba, unicode, codepages

I am using Excel 2007 on Windows 7 in Turkish.

It is said that Excel VBA uses UTF-8 for internal text representation.

There is something strange in case transformation beyond Turkish `"İ"` and `"ı"` transformation problem. The `UCase` and `LCase` functions do not transform `"İ"` and `"ı"` as said in Unicode data.

In Unicode data, it is said that the lowercase of `"İ"` (0x130) is `"i"` (0x69) and the uppercase of `"ı"` (0x131) is `"I"` (0x49). But VBA's `LCase` function for `"İ"` returns `"İ"` not `"i"`, and the `UCase` function for `"ı"` returns `"ı"` not `"I"`.

These transformations do not fit rules of Unicode. If VBA uses UTF-8, and UTF-8 is a Unicode transformation format, isn't it rationale to expect that transformations fit rules of Unicode at least? (Sorry for "at least")

And more, the `InStr`, `InstrRev`, `strComp`, `Replace` functions do not work right with the `vbTextCompare` option if text includes `"İ"` and `"ı"`, if the cases of these letters are different in the text parameters of functions.

eg. there is no way for `InStr` to find `"İnek"` in `"inek"`, and `strComp` does not return 0 even if it's used with the `vbTextCompare` option.

And much more, the worksheet function `UPPER`, `LOWER` can not be used inside VBA code. These are documented but non-existent.

What is the rule of VBA when transforming letter cases? The answer is also relevant to the `vbTextCompare` option.

---

Added section after comments:

First of all, it is a known issue that Turkish `"İ"` and `"ı"` case transformations and matching of different cases of these letters can not be done properly.

This issue is related to some other topics: [Why does Unicode implement the Turkish I the way it does?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48067545/)

In Turkish:

Lowercase `"I"` is `"ı"`
Lowercase `"İ"` is `"i"`
Uppercase `"ı"` is `"I"`
Uppercase `"i"` is `"İ"`

In Turkish Excel
`=LOWER("I")` is `"i"`
`=LOWER("İ")` is `"i"`
`=UPPER("ı")` is `"I"`
`=UPPER("i")` is `"I"`

When functions are used in the formulas in the cells, these are the results. Some of this results are not proper for Turkish, but fits Unicode rules (these functions are called with Turkish names on worksheet, of course). `UPPER` and `LOWER` functions can not be used as members of Worksheet functions in VBA code.

As Unicode data file,

Lower case of `I` (0x49) is `i` (0x69)
Lower case of `İ` (0x130) is `i` (0x69)
Upper case of `ı` (0x131) is `I` (0x49)
Upper case of `i` (0x69) is `I` (0x49)

This situation is weird, of course, but these are the rules.

`UCase("i")` returns `"I"` (This action is wrong for Turkish. It is expected, and there are no known solutions as I know. Fits rules of Unicode)
`Ucase("ı")` returns `"ı"` (This action is wrong for Turkish, also it does not fit rules of Unicode. This is unexpected)
`Lcase("I")` returns `"i"` (This action is wrong for Turkish. It is expected, and there are no known solutions as I know. Fits rules of Unicode)
`LCase("İ")` returns `"İ"` (This action is wrong for Turkish, also it does not fit rules of Unicode. This is unexpected)
`Instr(1, "İnek", "i", vbTextCompare)` returns `0` (Can not find)
`Instr(1, "Inek", "i", vbTextCompare)` returns `1` (Can be found as-is in English, not in Turkish)

Some replacements can not be done:
`Replace("Inek", "i", "Whatever", 1, -1, vbTextCompare)` returns `"Whatevernek"` (This is wrong for Turkish, but expected. Also fits the rules of Unicode)
`Replace("Inek", "ı", "Whatever", 1, -1, vbTextCompare)` returns `"Inek"`, not `"Whatevernek"` (This is wrong for Turkish, but expected. Also does not fit rules of Unicode, which is unexpected)
`Replace("İnek", "i", "Whatever", 1, -1, vbTextCompare)` returns `"İnek"`, not `"Whatevernek"` (This is wrong for Turkish, but expected. Also does not fit rules of Unicode, which is unexpected)
`Replace("İnek", "ı", "Whatever", 1, -1, vbTextCompare)` returns `"İnek"`, not `"Whatevernek"` (This is wrong for Turkish, but expected. There is no rule for this situation in Unicode)

and comparing can not be done:
`StrComp("İnek", "inek", vbTextCompare)` returns `1`, not `0` (This is wrong for Turkish, but expected. Also does not fit rules of Unicode, which is unexpected)
`StrComp("Inek", "ınek", vbTextCompare)` returns `-1`, not `0` (This is wrong for Turkish, but expected. Also does not fit rules of Unicode, which is unexpected)

The case conversion issue of Turkish `"İ"` and `"ı"` letters is known, and no simple solution exists as I know in VBA code.

I ask specifically which rule is used for case conversion and for matching, and why Unicode rules are not used.

`StrConv` function give results as `UCase` and `LCase` functions give:
`StrConv("I", vbLowerCase)` returns `"i"`
`StrConv("İ", vbLowerCase)` returns `"İ"`
`StrConv("ı", vbUpperCase)` returns `"ı"`
`StrConv("i", vbUpperCase)` returns `"I"`

The `CompareString` API function called with the `NORM_IGNORECASE` argument gives the same results as the `StrComp` function.

Comment: Does this one help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/18444087/16578424? I know I had the same issue with an international tool years ago ... but can't remember the solution :-(

Comment: Could you add something to try to reproduce your issue?

Comment: @Foxfire And Burns And Burns: I add some more explanations.

Comment: `It is said that Excel VBA uses UTF-8 for internal text representation` - it is NOT said, and if it is, then it is wrong. VBA uses UTF-16 for internal text representation. You may be confusing "UTF-8" with "Unicode", please see https://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html.

Comment: There appears to be two unrelated problems. One is that you are putting the Turkish characters into the VBA editor as literal strings. You [cannot do that](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24384952/11683). The other is the transformation of the characters on the sheet - the transformation you have shown is not what I see in my non-Turkish Office 2021 on my non-Turkish Windows , `=LOWER("I")` and `=LOWER("İ")` both return `i`, and `=UPPER("ı")` and `=UPPER("i")` both return `I`, so your results may vary in different Excels even when you don't involve VBA.

Comment: @GSerg Thanks, You may be right. I know that article. UTF-16 is Windows's text representation. A web search returns that VBA's internal text representation is UTF-8. But I don't know. Is there a Microsoft document? And, more importantly, being UTF-16 makes no difference about my question.

Comment: Cannot find one at the moment, but VBA strings are [`BSTR`s](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/automat/bstr), they consist of `OLECHAR`s which are `WCHAR`s, and those [are UTF-16](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog/windows-data-types#LPCWSTR). In any case VBA does not handle the text itself, it asks the OS to do that. Try storing your characters on the sheet, as opposed to in the code, see if that makes a difference. If it doesn't, then that is what the OS is giving you.

Comment: @GSerg And I make some correction on my post, in Turkish Excel the UPPER and LOWER functions work same as you have written, and not proper for Turkish. But this way of working fits Unicode rules. Ant my question is still unanswered.

Comment: Not tested but did you try `StrComp` with `vbBinaryCompare`?

Comment: @Foxfire And Burns And Burns `vbBinaryCompare` matches if characters are binary equal, there is no problem in that situation. The idea is, matching same word containing different cases of the letters like "İnek" and "inek". For this vbTextCompare should be used; vbBinaryCompare do not match in this stiuation.

Comment: `my question is still unanswered` - I don't think anyone can answer exactly what and how happens there. It is a poorly done implementation detail. You have four different behaviours: `=LOWER()`, `LCase()`, `StrConv(vbLowerCase)` and `StrConv(vbLowerCase, 1055)` all return different things for the letter `ı` (same for the UPPER variants). You cannot affect any of them. If you want some consistency, pick one and/or use OS functions for string comparisons such as `CompareStringEx`.

Comment: @GSerg I added results with StrConv and CompareString (not CompareStringEx) StrConv is same Ucase and LCase, CompareString is same as StrComp; no difference. You are right about that implementation detail is poorly done.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57924848/turkish-excel-version-transforming-dotted-upper-i-%C4%B0-to-dotless-upper-i-i-w

Comment: @Hans Passant Thanks. I've seen than topic. Uppercasing, and lowercasing have solutions like `UCase(Replace(Replace("MyString", "ı", "I"), "i", "İ"))` and `LCase(Replace(Replace("MyString", "I", "ı"), "İ", "i"))`. And and other case insensitive operations (`StrComp`, `InStr`, `InStrRev`) also can be done after uppercasing or lowercasing both text arguments, with using vbBinaryCompare in this situation. I'd like to learn using which rules VBA (or windows) makes case insensitive comparison. Because it seems some functions use Unicode rules, others not and if there are simple solutions.

Comment: @kitapmitap They are not the same, they are all different. If they are the same for you, you are doing something wrong (likely you keep hardcoding the letters in the VBA code which destroys them). See https://i.stack.imgur.com/IKXeq.png.

Comment: @GSerg https://imgur.com/lB1BoQe Mostly same.

Comment: @GSerg There are differences in `StrConv(vbLowerCase)` and `StrConv(vbupperCase)` . LOWER and UPPER functions fits unicode rules. Is it really `StrConv(vbupperCase)` converts  "İ" to "I"; some weird. Because if the case is same with argument, character is left unchanged.

Comment: @GSerg My results is nearly same as yours. And in my application `LCase` and `StrConv(vbLowerCase)` and `StrConv(vbLowerCase, 1055)` are same with each other. At the same time `UCase` and `StrConv(vbupperCase)` and `StrConv(vbUpperCase, 1055)` are same with each other. `LOWER` and `UPPER` are different from this three.

Comment: You will have to look into some Windows API functions to solve this issue. The documentation of [`CharLowerBuffW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-charlowerbuffw) references this issue and recommends the use of the [`LCMapStringW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnls/nf-winnls-lcmapstringw) function. The point made in the comments that non-ASCII characters in the VBE are unsafe holds regardless... Maybe you can use [this library](https://github.com/guwidoe/VBA-StringTools) to work around this issue.